# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ";" in

Tags: php

Hola buenas estoy arrancando con php y tengo algun error de sintaxis en mi codigo, lo que estoy intentendo es un simple form de contacto pero no puedo hacerlo que funcione, el error de sintaxis esta entre estas lineas de codigo, ya lo relei varias veces pero no logro encontrar el error, desde ya mucgas gracias

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ";" in C:\xampp\htdocs\integradora_utn\index.php on line 172

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['btn_cont'])){
    $nombre_cont = $_POST['nombre_cont'];
    $email = $_POST['email_cont'];
    $message = "Mensaje de prueba";

    $to     = 'example@hotmail.com';
    $subject ="Contacto Pagina";
    $headers = "From: $email" . '\r\n'.;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

    // EVENTO SI EL MENSAJE SE ENVIA CORRECTAMENTE
    echo '<script>alert("Gracias! $nombre_cont Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.");</script>';

}else{

    // EVENTO SI EL MENSAJE SE  NO SE ENVIA CORRECTAMENTE
    echo 'Mail failed to send';
}}
?>
```

Comment: Aquí: **`'\r\n'.;`** te sobra el punto del final

Comment: lo que dice @BetaM quitale el punto al final y listo

Comment: eso es otra pregunta